# Play video in Android that does not loop

Tags: android

**Goal**: 
Play a video that does not loop.

**Assumption**:
There is a flag or extra I can pass to specify this behavior.

**What I've tried**:
Looked through the `Intent.FLAG_*` possibilities.
Looking into `Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_*` possibilities.

The basic code as it stands right now:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
val data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", attachmentFile)
intent.setDataAndType(data, contentType)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

I can see a checkbox for looping in the default video player, but am not sure how to toggle it, or if I can at all.

[image]

Comment: Does unchecking loop video in the screenshot not help?

Comment: It does help, we're wondering if we can pass along a flag/metadata saying, "let's not loop this video, please"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see a checkbox for looping in the default video player

You are launching a third-party video player. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of different such players pre-installed across the 20,000+ device models and ~2 billion devices. There will be hundreds of other ones installed by users from the Play Store and elsewhere.

With that in mind:

- There is no "please don't loop" flag
- There is no requirement for a video player to honor that sort of flag

If you want complete control over video playback, do not use `ACTION_VIEW`, but instead play back the video yourself (`VideoView`, ExoPlayer, etc.).